# Regional Settings are not working in Tridion 2011 SP1

Tags: content-manager

After installing SDL Tridion 2011 SP1, the regional settings are not working properly.

For example: UK users are unable to see the Content Items/Pages Modified timestamp in their local region's format, e.g. "DD/MM/YYYY".

Thanks

Comment: Welcome to the Tridion community!  It would be great if you provided some more info on what research you've done and things you've tried/looked into.  Here is a guide on the how-to in order to get the most helpful answers: http://tridion.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: What are the settings in the user's preferences in Tridion?

Answer (score 3):

Do following:

- Go to User Preference and ensure it has Regional Settings set to English (United Kingdom) See the screen shot below:
  [image]
- Now you need to refresh the page (or at least the Folders/Structure group) to take this change in effect (If you have open up a folder in Content Manager Explorer then go to the User Preferences and change the Regional setting and come back to your previous location, the changes will not reflect unless you refreshes the Folder/Structure Group or the whole Browser)
- If it still does not work (Which is very unlikely), then clear your browser cache, close your browser, reopen the Content Manager Explorer in browser and check again